# How do i turn a UIImageVew or the image in it into a CGImage, and then back again?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, cgimage

I just don;t know how to do this. I want more flexibility to edit the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIImage instances have `CGImage` (read-only) property that allow access to CGImageRef image  data.
To create new UIImage from CGImageRef you can use convinience contructor:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)cgImage
```